# Function in getting the less than equal in the list and removing the duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I need to count how many less than or equal numbers in the list and disregarding the duplicates.

```
def getVal(prices = [5,5,10], money = 5):
        count = 0
        for i in prices:
            if money >= i and money == i:
                count += 1
        return count
```

the output of this code is:
`2`

How can I get the output of `1`.

Comment: If you want less than or equal, why are you using the condition `money >= i and money == i`? That is effectively just `money == i`. You probably want `money >= i` only.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your list into a set, and all the duplicate will be removed automatically:

```
def getVal(prices = [5,5,10], money = 5):
        count = 0
        for i in set(prices): # Add set() around the list to convert
            if money >= i:
                count += 1
        return count
print(getVal())
```

Output:

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner?

```
def getVal(prices, money):
    return sum(i <= money for i in set(prices))

print(getVal([5, 5, 10], 5))
```

Whenever you come across avoiding duplicates, the answer is always a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html).

Comment: There are countless cases where we also do not want to lose the order of the array. I believe you'd better restate that.